# Using SharpAvi to save screenshots to an AVI produces 100 frames of blank video

Tags: c#, gdi+, avi

My game takes a screenshot each game loop and stores it memory. The user can then press "print screen" to trigger "SaveScreenshot" (see code below) to store each screenshot as a PNG and also compile them into an AVI using SharpAvi. The saving of images works fine, and a ~2sec AVI is produced, but it doesn't show any video when played. It's just the placeholder VLC Player icon. I think this is very close to working, but I can't determine what's wrong. Please see my code below. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very appreciative!

```
    private Bitmap GrabScreenshot()
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data =
            bmp.LockBits(this.ClientRectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height, PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte,
                data.Scan0);
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            return bmp;
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // occasionally getting GDI generic exception when rotating the image... skip that one.
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void SaveScreenshots()
    {
        var directory = "c:\\helioscreenshots\\";
        var rootFileName = string.Format("{0}_", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);

        var writer = new AviWriter(directory + rootFileName + ".avi")
        {
            FramesPerSecond = 30,
            // Emitting AVI v1 index in addition to OpenDML index (AVI v2)
            // improves compatibility with some software, including 
            // standard Windows programs like Media Player and File Explorer
            EmitIndex1 = true
        };

        // returns IAviVideoStream
        var aviStream = writer.AddVideoStream();

        // set standard VGA resolution
        aviStream.Width = this.ClientSize.Width;
        aviStream.Height = this.ClientSize.Height;
        // class SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs contains FOURCCs for several well-known codecs
        // Uncompressed is the default value, just set it for clarity
        aviStream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed;
        // Uncompressed format requires to also specify bits per pixel
        aviStream.BitsPerPixel = BitsPerPixel.Bpp32;

        var index = 0;
        while (this.Screenshots.Count > 0)
        {
            Bitmap screenshot = this.Screenshots.Dequeue();

            var screenshotBytes = ImageToBytes(screenshot);

            // write data to a frame
            aviStream.WriteFrame(true, // is key frame? (many codecs use concept of key frames, for others - all frames are keys)
                              screenshotBytes, // array with frame data
                              0, // starting index in the array
                              screenshotBytes.Length); // length of the data

            // save it!
            // NOTE: compared jpeg, gif, and png. PNG had smallest file size.
            index++;
            screenshot.Save(directory + rootFileName + index + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        // save the AVI!
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static byte[] ImageToBytes(Image img)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.Screenshots.Count`?

Comment: 100 - I've verified that the AVI contains 100 frames at time of closing. When I play it it will last for over 2 seconds, which is what you would expect, it just doesn't show anything...

Comment: If you look at the pngs saved on disk (`screenshot.Save`) do they look correct?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you're providing the byte-array in png-encoding, yet the stream is configured as `KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed`.

Furthermore, from the [manual](https://github.com/baSSiLL/SharpAvi/wiki/Using-Video-Encoders):

> AVI expects uncompressed data in format of standard Windows DIB, that is bottom-up bitmap of the specified bit-depth. For each frame, put its data in byte array and call IAviVideoStream.WriteFrame()
>
> Next, all encoders expect input image data in specific format. It's BGR32 top-down - 32 bits per pixel, blue byte first, alpha byte not used, top line goes first. This is the format you can often get from existing images. [...] So, you simply pass an uncompressed top-down BGR32

I would retrieve the byte-array directly from the `Bitmap` using `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy` as described in the manual.